# Tadpole diagram and vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, vacuum

[This statement may be well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadpole_(physics)). For many **massless** theories, these **tadpole diagram graphs vanish in dimensional regularization (by dimensional analysis and the absence of any inherent mass scale in the loop integral).**

[image]

How can one show this is QFT statement is true(tadpole diagram graphs vanish) regardless the coupling, say by Yukawa-Higgs via $\lambda \bar{\Psi} \phi \Psi$ or by gauge field $g \bar{\Psi} \gamma^\mu A_\mu \Psi$, etc? i.e. does not depend on $\lambda,g$ or an energy cutoff $\Lambda$?

Comment: if there is a soliton background, then it shall not be zero due to Jackiw-Rebbi or Goldstone-Wilczek effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a **soliton background** (of dashed lines), then this tadpole diagram with extended legs like

[image]

shall **not be zero due to Jackiw-Rebbi or Goldstone-Wilczek effect**; the soliton background (dashed lines) will induce nontrivial (fractionalized) induced quantum numbers (or simply the charge or vacuum expectation value) for the scalar bosons (solid line); even if the original scalar bosons(solid line) are massless.

For example. see the [bosonic anomaly in](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.91.195134) [arxiv-1403.5256 - Bosonic Anomaly, Induced Fractional Quantum Number and Degenerate Zero Modes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5256).

Interestingly, such an effect takes place on the surface of **Symmetry Protected Topological(SPT) States** as noticed in [this Ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5256). And see Reference therein, e.g. about [J. Goldstone and F. Wilczek, Phys. Rev. Lett. 47, 986 (1981)](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.986) and [R. Jackiw and C. Rebbi, Phys. Rev. D 13, 3398 (1976)](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.13.3398).